# get the ObjectInputStream to see the different objects

Tags: java, client, objectinputstream

I'm making a server-client application. There are two parts on my application a chat part and a game part. 
When I do the chatting I send String objects, when I play my game it sends Game objects to the other computer. 
How could I make my ObjectInputStream see the difference between the two kinds of object.
I've been trying something like that:

```
if (input.readObject().getClass().isAssignableFrom(Game.class)){
                 game1 = (Game) input.readObject();
                  output.writeObject(game1);
                  output.flush();
             }else{
                 message = (String) input.readObject();
                 output.writeObject(message);
                 output.flush();
             }
```

it throws NotSerializableException when I'd like to use the game object, however the chatpart is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `Game` object implement `Serializable`?  It has to if you want to be able to read/write it using `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream`.

Moreover, in addition to making `Game` serializable, the same applies to every field declared in the `Game` class.  Each one must either implement `Serializable` or be declared as a `transient` (or `static`) member.  If these conditions are not met, you will get a `NotSerializableException` when you try to write the object.

**Edit:**

There are some other issues in your code as well.  For one thing, you are calling `readObject()` too many times.  I'd suggest trying something like:

```
Object next = input.readObject();
if (next instanceof Game) {
    game1 = (Game)next;
    //...
}
else if (next instanceof String) {
    message = (String)next;
    //...
}
else {
    System.out.println("Unexpected object type:  " + next.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: you were right, I didn't impement serializable.
but now it says Game cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
it jumps to the else branch when I use the game part.

Comment: @user1707095 - Yes, there were other issues as well.  See the edit above.

Comment: now it works only once, when I call this method over and over again it gives back the first Game object.
the chat part is still works well.